# подставляемое значение из переменной в php код

Tags: php

Есть код

```
<?php  
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
<login>************</login>
<password>************</password>
<action>send</action>
<text>TEXT</text>

<to number='88888888888'>
</to>
</data>";

$address = "https://lcab.smsint.ru/API/XML/send.php";
$ch = curl_init($address);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $address);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

он отправляет автоматическое смс через сервер

в данном моменте телефон уже подставлен 88888888888

и есть форма входа

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="name" name="number" placeholder="ТЕЛ" type="text">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Войти">
<span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
```

необходимо подставить значение   name="number"   точнее $_POST['number']
заместо  телефона 88888888888.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
<login>************</login>
<password>************</password>
<action>send</action>
<text>TEXT</text>

<to number='" . $_POST['number'] . "'>
</to>
</data>";
```

Comment: <to number='" . $_POST['number'] . "'> Вариант не плохой ошибок код не видит,  но СМС  не отправляется якобы символы не понятны ему, необходимо htmlspecialchars — Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности

Answer (score 1):

Тут все верно Сори за беспокойство ошибка была в лишних пробелах пред скобками to